# Spring Cloud Load Balance and Feign Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, load-balancing

I have been using `spring-clound-openfeign` with Consul as the service registry and Ribbon as Load Balancer. I am currently working with spring-boot 2.3.10.RELEASE.

I really like spring-cloud-feign-inheritance support which, in my understanding, allows me to write a single interface used by the server side and the client side.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-inheritance

From spring-boot `2.4.x` onward, the spring team recommended replacing Ribbon by `spring-clould-loadbanced` as a replacement since Ribbon is no longer being maintained.

If I have an interface let say:

```java
interface Greeting {
   @GetMapping
   String hello(String name);
}
```

By using Spring Openfeign +  Ribbon + Consul I could just extend it with:

```java
@FeignClient(name="my-service-id")
interface GreetingClient extends Greeting { }
```

And with that I would have a client implementation with load balanced capabilities.

Can I still accomplish the same result as `spring-cloud-openfeign` with `spring-clould-loadbalancer` or I really need to work with `RestTemplate` or `DiscoveryClient` to have the client side of my API?

An over all picture of this would be highly appreciated since nonwhere else I have found a sensible answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want get work like with ribbon, need connect spring cloud loadbalancer to consul. You can read how connnect spring cloud loadbalanncer to consul into link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#serviceregistry

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30205637)

Comment: The ideal answer would be a minimal working example of a project that uses feign client, spring load balancer and consul.